# putting dates into an array

Tags: php, arrays, date

Ok currently I have an array.. It looks something like:

```
array(
    ['march'] => array(
        '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '23', '24', '25', '30'
    );
);
```

Just as an example. How would I take those days in that march array, an do this:

03/02/2012 - 03/06/2012
03/23/2012 - 03/25/2012
03/30/2012

Anyone?

Comment: have you tried something already? if so, show us please.

Comment: Please see the selected answer below. This works.

Comment: I'm not interested in the solution. I am interested in seeing what you have tried before asking the question, e.g. in the code that didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the consecutive timespans by looping through your array like so:

```
    $months = array(
        'march' => array(
            '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '23', '24', '25', '30'
        )
    );

    $current_day = 0;
    $span_start = 0;
    $span_end = 0;

    foreach($months['march'] as $day) {

      if ($day > ++$current_day) {
        $current_day = $day;

        if ($span_start) {
          // print it out:
          echo "$span_start..$span_end\n";
        }

        $span_start = $day;
      }

      $span_end = $day;

    }

    // print the last one:
    echo "$span_start..$span_end";
```

For formatting/parsing/printing the dates, however, others' suggestion to use the built in `time` and `date` functions are absolutely correct.

Comment: You'll need to change the output to meet your needs, of course, but hopefully this illustrates grabbing the date range.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(
    '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '23', '24', '25', '30'
);

foreach($array as $date){
     echo '03/'.$date.'/2012;
}
```

You may need to add a zero before single unit dates!

Comment: This isn't using the expected input.

Comment: Yea that would just echo out each day, I need to pull 2 to 6 then 23 to 25 and 30th seperately

Comment: Oh i get it, was a pleasure anyway! Cheers!